# Can EmailValidator be used in standard laravel validation?

Tags: laravel, validation, email

I want to install https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator package to extend email validation rules, but
reading the doc I did not find if there is a way to use this plugin in standard laravel validation, like :

```
   'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer is "Yes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Laravel After Validation hooks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#after-validation-hook) like:

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);

$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    $emailValidator = new EmailValidator();
    $multipleValidations = new MultipleValidationWithAnd([
        new RFCValidation(),
        new DNSCheckValidation()
    ]);
    if ($emailValidator->isValid("example@example.com", $multipleValidations)) {
        $validator->errors()->add('field', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
    }
});
```